# Помогите составить sql запрос с JOIN, группировкой и условием

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

FamilyMembers

(pk)member_id - INT |
status - VARCHAR |
member_name - VARCHAR

Payments

(pk)payment_id - INT |
(fk)family_member - INT |
good - INT |
unit_price - INT |
date

Нужно узнать кто из членов семьи сколько потратил в 2005 году.

Составил такой запрос:
SELECT status, sum(unit_price) as costs FROM FamilyMembers
JOIN Payments ON family_member=member_id GROUP BY status;

Но никак не получается добавить сюда условие WHERE year(date)=2005

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить корректный запрос.

Comment: Поищите ключевое слово `HAVING` должно помочь

Comment: Вообще where в указанном виде должно отработать, хотя я бы написал что то вроде `WHERE date >= '2005-01-01' and date < '2006-01-01'`. А что именно с ним не получилось ? Если что, where пишется перед group by.

Comment: И group by странный, если надо выдать по членам семьи, то группировать надо видимо по member_id